# Keyboard hidden edittext and there isn't scroll ANDROID

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, hidden

I done a form with 5 edittexts but when the keyboard is going to show the last two edittext I can't see.

Only way to switch to the next fields is to use the buttons on the keyboard.

There is any solution to add a scroll without use the buttons?

I tried with sdk 3, resize keyboard and other things like that.

Answer (score 5):

Why not keep the entire layout in a scrollview. And add the attribute to the activity in manifest file

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
```

So when the keyboard is shown, the layout will be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Have you tried adding the android:windowSoftInputMode tag to your activity in the manifest?  From what you are describing I would think that either adjustResize or adjustPan should work.